# How do I redirect /search/ to wordpress search template?

Tags: search, template-redirect

I have a typical Wordpress site, with a typical Search page template set up which uses the typical GET format

```
    <form id="searchform" action="http://example.com" method="get">
        <input id="s" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Again">
    </form>
```

For users' convenience, I'd like to have the following url redirect to the search page template:

```
http://example.com/search/
```

But since there is no /search page or post it doesn't. It throws a 404.

So what I want is for...

```
http://example.com/search/
```

...to behave like:

```
http://example.com/?s=
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You might be able to use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) but I've been playing with it and haven't had much luck.

Comment: Thanks. It just looks so ugly to have the /?s= parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect). Here a simple redirection function.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'se219663_template_redirect' );

function se219663_template_redirect()
{
  global $wp_rewrite;

  if ( is_search() && ! empty ( $_GET['s'] )  )
  {
    $s         = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ); // or get_query_var( 's' )
    $location  = '/';
    $location .= trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->search_base );
    $location .= user_trailingslashit( urlencode( $s ) );
    $location  = home_url( $location );
    wp_safe_redirect( $location, 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Rule without search query, like this ( don't forget go to Permalink Settings to flush the rules ):

```
add_filter( 'search_rewrite_rules', 'se219663_search_rewrite_rules', 10, 1 );
function se219663_search_rewrite_rules( $rewrite )
{
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $rules = array(
    $wp_rewrite->search_base . '/?$' => 'index.php?s=',
  );
  $rewrite = $rewrite + $rules;
  return $rewrite;
 }
```

and redirect with empty search query, just use isset, modified from the code above.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'se219663_template_redirect' );

function se219663_template_redirect()
{
  global $wp_rewrite;

  if ( is_search() && isset ( $_GET['s'] )  )
  {
    $s         = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ); // or get_query_var( 's' )
    $location  = '/';
    $location .= trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->search_base );
    $location .= ( ! empty ( $s ) ) ? user_trailingslashit( urlencode( $s ) ) : urlencode( $s );
    $location  = home_url( $location );
    wp_safe_redirect( $location, 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work unless there is a search parameter. What I want is if the user types example.com/search/ it -still- brings them to the Search page. Can it be modified to do that?

Comment: do you mean search without search query? if you need keep empty search query in search page, you must use rewrite rule to keep them in search page.

Comment: I wanted exactly what the OP explained and tested them all. It was the second snippet that achieved /search/ -> ?s=. In other words, if the user navigations to /search/, the search results template (search.php) will be shown.